# How to determine if a value falls within a specific angle range on a circle?

Tags: geometry, range

I'm attempting to pick random colors from a specific range on the HSL color wheel.  What is the best way to determine if an angular value falls within an angular range on a circle when that range crosses over the 360/0 point of the circle?

For example, if I needed to pick a random value between 355 and 5 degrees.  So 1 would be an acceptable value in this example, but 180 would not.

Is there an easier way to do this other than checking if the value is between 355-360 and 0-5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case it is simpler to check `if angle <=5 or angle >= 355`

In general case to check whether angle `a` lies in range with middle value `m` and half-angle `h` (range `m-h..m+h`), to account for periodicity etc, one can use expression

```
if cos(a - m) > cos(h)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. The general case was what I was looking for.  I'd love to know why `cos(a-m) > cos(h)` represents this.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Consider middle angle=0. Angles +/- h at the circle lie at the same vertical line with x=cos(h). Point at the right of this line are close to zero angle than h. The same is true for arbitrary middle angle. Will add picture.

Comment: Thank you for the diagram.  Explains perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize all the angles to the range `[0°, 360°)`. If the allowed sector ranges from `a` to `b` counter-clockwise and `c` is the angle to be tested, the condition is

```
(a < b and a < c < b) or (a > b and b < c < a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could shift it backwards by the offset (in your case 355deg) and then take the modulo on 360 and compare to the range(in your case 10deg)

```
((x - 355) % 360) < 10
```

However some languages give negative answers to the modulo of a negative number, so it may be more reliable to shift up rather than down (and beware of negative x)

```
((x+5) % 360) < 10
```